# Is there a way to hide all but the last header asterisk in emacs org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I really like org and org-bullets and I'd like to entirely hide the leading asterisks for headers so that the headers (and their nifty icons/bullets) are flush with the left of the window.

I found this function in a Reddit thread, and it seems to mostly do what I want, except that it removes ALL of the asterisks. I want to keep the last one.

```
(defun me-org-mode-remove-stars ()
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil
   '(("^\\*+ "
      (0
       (prog1 nil
         (put-text-property (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)
                            'invisible t)))))))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'me-org-mode-remove-stars)
```

Being rather new to emacs and lisp in general, my first thought was to just modify the regular expression, but it turns out there's no lookahead here so I'm having trouble expressing "select all asterisks in a series except an asterisk followed by a space character" or something similar.

Is there a right way to go about this?

Comment: You could try using groups in the search expression (e.g. "^\\\(\\\*\\\)\\\* " and then use argument 1 for the match functions? Untested.

Comment: There should have been a + after the first asterisk or maybe a *.

Comment: That got closer, the top level headings got their bullet but the child headings still don't. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe show what you tried to see if we can tell why the subheadings don't work?

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the variable `org-hide-leading-stars` to the `t`, then it will hide all leading stars from the header.  You can even enable or disable that for specific files using the org-mode directives.  See built-in documentation (`C-h v  org-hide-leading-stars`) & [info pages](https://orgmode.org/manual/Hard-indentation.html#Hard-indentation) for more details. (I personally use it)

P.S. There is another way to do that - via [`org-ident-mode`](https://orgmode.org/manual/Org-Indent-Mode.html#Org-Indent-Mode), but I haven't tried it.

Comment: This effectively hides the leading stars, but keeps the indentation visually (the stars are still there). The function from my original post visually removes them, giving me this: https://i.imgur.com/JJpr7jD.png

My goal is to achieve the above image, but with one visible bullet for every heading.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question then - the title reads differently